# How to use app/console command line for Symfony on shared servers?

Tags: symfony

How to use app/console command line on shared servers?

When I try to flush de cache for example with:

```
app/console cache:clear -e prod;
```

I keep getting this kind of errors:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS),
>   expecting identifier (T_STRING) in
>   /home/clients/f61b2e8462ca91d597e79838efafc0d1/krown/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/ProxyGenerator.php
>   on line 62
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting
>   identifier (T_STRING) in
>   /home/clients/f61b2e8462ca91d597e79838efafc0d1/krown/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/ProxyGenerator.php
>   on line 62
>
> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>   Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting
>   identifier (T_STRING)

In my dedicated server I dont' have this kind of error. The same PHP version (7.1) is installed in both servers.

Comment: This looks like a PHP version problem. What does php -v show?

Comment: This question is already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them

Comment: Thank you @Chris, thanks to your comment I realized that the PHP version installed in the user PATH when connecting with SSH was the 5.4 instead 7.1 (as configured in Admin Panel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue by forcing the PHP version appending it to all my "app/console" queries, for example:

```
php-7.1 app/console cache:clear -e prod
php-7.1 app/console cache:clear -e dev
php-7.1 app/console doctrine:generate:entity
php-7.1 app/console doctrine:generate:entities Front
php-7.1 app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
php-7.1 app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```